# What is the best practice for multiple colors in a sentence in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I know I want to keep my style and my content separate, so assuming I want to display:

```
<h1>ROYGBV</h1>
```

on a page, where each letter is also its matching color, what would be the best practice for this?

Would it be:

```
<h1><font color="red">R</font><font color="orange">O</font>
```

and so on? And assuming that I have multiple words in a paragraph that needed to be colored like:

> Sally found all the RED seashells down by the BLUE seashore out in the YELLOW sun ...

Is it ok to have font tags all over your HTML? The only alternative I can think of is putting it them in span tags and adding a class. This would allow me to change my definition of red in the css file for all iterations of red.

Comment: No, it's not. The font tag has been deprecated since HTML 4. Use span and classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<font>` tag is deprecated. [**MDN Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)

Best way is in your question itself. Using span to wrap a particular word.

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>Sally found all the <span class="red">RED</span> seashells down by the <span class="blue">BLUE</span> seashore out in the <span class="yellow">YELLOW</span> sun ...</p>
```

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I was looking for a magical, cleaner, shorthand that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this..

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gq237zzg/).

Here is the snippet.

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>Sally found all the <span class="red">RED</span> seashells down by the <span class="blue">BLUE</span> seashore out in the <span class="yellow">YELLOW</span> sun</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<style type="text/css">
.classForColor {
color: red;
}
</style>

...

<body>
<span class="classForColor">txt</span>
</body>
```

Comment: The question was about best practice. Why is your solution the best?